# Angular Shopping List ng-repeat not valid

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a shopping list in Angular - and I cannot get my ng-repeat to work. {{food}} is all that will show up when I am trying to add something to my list.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Shopping List Angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">

    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in foods">{{ item.name }}</li>
            <li> {{foods}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Item"  ng-model=""></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" ng-model=""></input>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

        var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) { 
  $scope.foods = [
    {name: 'Kale', cost: $2.00},
    {name: 'Tofu', cost: $3.00},
    {name: 'Spinach', cost: $6.00},
    {name: 'Onion', cost: $1.00}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript code, you're missing quotes to represent cost as a string. Try this:

```
$scope.foods = [
    {name: 'Kale', cost: '$2.00'},
    {name: 'Tofu', cost: '$3.00'},
    {name: 'Spinach', cost: '$6.00'},
    {name: 'Onion', cost: '$1.00'}
];
```

Comment: Thank you! It also worked when I removed the $ symbol altogether without adding them as strings.